# A question about the monotonicity of $y_1 = x^e$ and $y_2 = x^{\pi}$

Tags: exponential-function, monotone-functions

As we know from 1st year Calculus, for function $f(x) = x^n, x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n$ is odd, the $f(x)$ is increasing; if $n$ is even $f(x)$ is increasing when $x \geq 0$ and decreasing when $x<0$. But here we only have the cases where $n$ is a positive integer. We don't know how it goes if $n$ is replaced by some irrational number like $\pi$ or $e$.

So I tried to do the plot of $y_1 = x^e$ and $y_2 = x^{\pi}$ through MATLAB to study their monotonicity, and here are the codes and plots of them:

$\textbf{Codes}:$

[image: Codes]

$\textbf{Plots}:$

[image: Plots]

And from the plots above, we can see that $y_1 = x^e$ and $y_2 = x^{\pi}$ are monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, and I am quite curious about how to rigorously prove the monotonicity of them. Can somebody give me some hint on which mathematical tool I should use here, for example derivative or what? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see there is a **warning** given which says that the imaginary parts are ignored.

It is actually trying to say that in the case of functions like these we cannot have $x<0$ because then we will get an imaginary number. (Recall that $\textrm{(-ve number)}^{\textrm{irrational}}$ yeilds an imaginary number.)

Now let's say that you define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ and now you want to study the nature of the curve when $x<0$. Then this is actually absurd as there is no such thing as "larger number" in complex numbers.

Suppose $x<0$ then let $x=-a$ where $a>0$. Now $$(-a)^{e}=(-1)^ea^e$$
$$=(e^{i\pi})^e a^e=a^e\cdot e^{i\pi e}$$
$$=a^e(\cos(\pi e)+i\sin(\pi e))$$
which is indeed a complex number.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you please explain why if $x<0$ then we may have complex number here?

Comment: @ZYX I've added some explanation...hope you find it helpful

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand it now.